# How to write a function that accepts a `Vec` of borrowed or owned elements?

Tags: rust, ownership

In Rust, how can I pass a vector of owned objects to a function that expects a vector of borrowed objects? Is my only option to create a new vector?

What is the best practice for the signature of a function in which I care about the type of the contained generic of a struct but don't care about if it is borrowed or not?

Example situation:

```
fn using_vec_of_borrows(borrows: &Vec<&String>) {
    //...
}

fn main() {
    let foo: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    using_vec_of_borrows(&foo);
}
```

How could I write `using_vec_of_borrows()` so that it accepts a vector of borrowed strings or a vector of owned strings? Or if it was part of an external library, could I convert my vector of owned strings to a vector of borrowed strings without iterating over it?

Keep in mind here that `String` is just used as an example type. It could be anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question [How to get a slice of references from a vector in Rust?](/q/37797242/2189130) You need to create a new `Vec` via `foo.iter().collect()`. See the fix applied on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f7e0e913a8e007afaec2ba4d7eb8b446).

Comment: No it doesn't, because the question asks if it is possible to have a function that accepts both borrowed content and owned content, and also if it is possible to make a vector of owned content pass as a vector of borrowed without new iterattion.

Comment: There seem to be multiple questions. You should focus on one per post, but to answer these: no, it's not possible for a function to accept both borrowed content and owned content, BUT it is possible for the content to be either borrowed or owned (see [cow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html)). In general, if you have a `Vec<T>`, it's not possible to get a `Vec<&T>` without recreating it. Picturing yourself the memory layout should make that clear.

Comment: @BlackBeans thanks! kmdreko shown however in his answer that it is indeed possible to have a method that takes either owned or not owned vector content.

Comment: @Barracuda yes, you could have accomplished something similar with Cow, depending on what the wanted semantic. But there is a difference between "a function that accepts both &T and T" and "a function that accepts a Something<T>" where `Something<T>` can have the semantics of `&T` or `T`, which was my point (the first is impossible, the second is possible).

Comment: Very fair, and yes I do unterstand your point that at a low level, it's not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting @trent from [this answer](/a/62217143/2189130):

> When you hear "generic over references and non-references", think [`Borrow<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html).

Making your function generic over elements that implement `Borrow<String>` will allow it to accept both a `&Vec<String>` and `&Vec<&String>`:

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn using_vec_of_borrows<T: Borrow<String>>(borrows: &[T]) {
    //...
}

fn main() {
    let foo: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    using_vec_of_borrows(&foo);
    
    let foo: Vec<&String> = Vec::new();
    using_vec_of_borrows(&foo);
}
```

You can even change it to an iterator for more flexibility if the elements don't need to be contiguous.

Note: I changed the signature from `&Vec<T>` to `&[T]` since the latter is more idiomatic. And I would've changed `Borrow<String>` into `Borrow<str>` for a similar reason, but `&String` does not implement `Borrow<str>`.

See also:

- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question about the method signature!

Comment: I try to use the Borrow solution, but it is not working with complex structs like Regex (from the crate of the same name).  I can't call methods implemented by the struct.  I get an error `no method named 'is_match' found for reference &R in the current scope`. https://gist.github.com/rust-play/23b73d813bc55ad38bb62d8c57be8f13

Comment: NVM I was dumb, I need to add an explicit call to `.borrow()` to use it. A bit annoying.